# Why aren't my class library methods appearing in my referenced console application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, reference, class-library

I have written a class library. To execute methods that I wrote in my class library, I created a console application. In my console application, I added the class library that I wrote as a reference. I then added the appropriate `using` statement to my console application. My methods from this library are inaccessible currently. Why?

Here's my class library with a basic method. It was created in .NET framework 3.5.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DataSourcesGDB;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;

namespace RelateTablesValidation
{

    [Guid("e1058544-0d84-49be-a406-b4e65707f95b")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    [ProgId("RelateTablesValidation.Validate")]
    [ComVisible(true)]



    public class Validate : ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IClassExtension, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IObjectClassExtension, ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase.IRelatedObjectClassEvents2 

    {

    public void ChangeClassExtension(IObjectClass objectClass, String extensionUID, IPropertySet extensionProperties)
            {
                ISchemaLock schemaLock = (ISchemaLock)objectClass;

                try
                {
                    // Attempt to get an exclusive schema lock.
                    schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriExclusiveSchemaLock);

                    // Cast the object class to the IClassSchemaEdit2 interface.
                    IClassSchemaEdit2 classSchemaEdit = (IClassSchemaEdit2)objectClass;

                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(extensionUID))
                    {
                        // Create a unique identifier (UID) object and change the extension.
                        UID extUID = new UIDClass();
                        extUID.Value = extensionUID;
                        classSchemaEdit.AlterClassExtensionCLSID(extUID, extensionProperties);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Clear the class extension.
                        classSchemaEdit.AlterClassExtensionCLSID(null, null);
                    }
                }
                catch (COMException comExc)
                {
                    throw new Exception("Could not change class extension.", comExc);
                }
                finally
                {
                    schemaLock.ChangeSchemaLock(esriSchemaLock.esriSharedSchemaLock);
                }
            }
}
```

Here's my console app. RelateTablesValidation is the class library. Also created in .NET Framework 3.5

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using RelateTablesValidation;
using Esri.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.DatasourcesGDB;

    namespace ApplyClassExtension
    {
    class Program
        {


            [STAThread()]
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                //system sees objects from this namespace OK
                IWorkspaceFactory workspaceFactory = new FileGDBWorkspaceFactory(); 


                //now when i try to call my method, it doesn't even show up in Intellisense
                ChangeClassExtension(method params would go here);

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gee I wish I could see your code so that I could help you.. but you didn't provide any.

Comment: Is the library using an incompatible .NET framework? For example, did you create a Silverlight library, or one targeting a higher version of .NET (say 4.5) whereas your console application is targeting 3.5?

Comment: Can you show us how you're trying to call the methods?

Comment: Sure. I added some more code to the second box. I'm simply trying to type the method from inside Main.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do what you're trying to do.

All methods in C# are inside of objects. You must either make the method `static` and call it like this:

```
Validate.ChangeClassExtension(...);
```

Or don't make it static and instantiate an instance of `Validate`:

```
var val = new Validate();
val.ChangeClassExtension(...);
```

Comment: I figured it was something simple like this. Could you elaborate on why you would want to use one way over the other?

Comment: `static` methods are generally used for methods that are related to a type (in your case `Validate`) but don't require state from an instance of that class. Your class doesn't appear to have any state at all (fields, properties, etc). Therefore, you can make the class itself `static` and the method `static` (the method _must_ be `static` if you make the class `static`).